# How can I have multiple common table expressions in a single SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am in the process of simplifying a complicated select statement, so thought I would use common table expressions.

Declaring a single cte works fine.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT * from cdr.Location
    )

select * from cte1
```

Is it possible to declare and use more than one cte in the same SELECT?

ie this sql gives an error

```
WITH cte1 as (
    SELECT * from cdr.Location
)

WITH cte2 as (
    SELECT * from cdr.Location
)

select * from cte1    
union     
select * from cte2
```

the error is

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

NB. I have tried putting semicolons in and get this error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

Probably not relevant but this is on SQL 2008.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I think it should be something like:

```
WITH 
    cte1 as (SELECT * from cdr.Location),
    cte2 as (SELECT * from cdr.Location)
select * from cte1 union select * from cte2
```

Basically, `WITH` is just a clause here, and like the other clauses that take lists, "," is the appropriate delimiter.

Comment: Don't forget that `cte2` can reference `cte1` like so: ... cte2 as (SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE ...)

Comment: what about declaring recursive and non-recursive expressions?

Answer (score 18):

Above mentioned answer is right:

```
WITH 
    cte1 as (SELECT * from cdr.Location),
    cte2 as (SELECT * from cdr.Location)
select * from cte1 union select * from cte2
```

Aditionally, You can also query from cte1 in cte2 :

```
WITH 
    cte1 as (SELECT * from cdr.Location),
    cte2 as (SELECT * from cte1 where val1 = val2)

select * from cte1 union select * from cte2
```

`val1,val2` are just asumptions for expressions..

Hope this blog will also help :
http://iamfixed.blogspot.de/2017/11/common-table-expression-in-sql-with.html

Comment: what about declaring recursive and non-recursive expressions?