# multiple cte in single select statement where ctes can refer to each other 

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Expanding on following question ([Multiple Select Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584284/how-can-i-have-multiple-common-table-expressions-in-a-single-select-statement)) I would like to know if I can do following:

```
WITH 
    cte1 as (
      SELECT * from cdr.Location
    ),
    cte2 as (
      SELECT * from cdr.Location
        WHERE cdr.Location.someField = cte1.SomeField
    )
select * from cte1 union select * from cte2
```

So accent here is on following line:

```
 WHERE cdr.Location.someField = cte1.SomeField
```

where within cte2 I'm referencing cte1 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can reference previously declared CTEs in subsequent CTEs:

```
WITH cte1 as (
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM cdr.Location t),
     cte2 as (
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM cdr.Location t
    JOIN cte1 c1 ON c1.somefield = t.someField)
SELECT * 
  FROM cte1 
UNION 
SELECT * 
  FROM cte2
```

**NOTES**

1. Joining onto cte2 in the cte1 declaration wouldn't work, because the statement is executed from top down.
2. You reference a CTE like any other inline view (which it is) or table/temp table/etc by JOINing on whatever you need.

BTW: Try to formulate a better example in the future - it's good for you and the rest of the SO community who are trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Did you follow link to question that I was expanding? I don't see any problem with example given the context.