# Search stored procedure that returns total records found, is very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

i have the below stored procedure, it work great without returning the total record, but when i return the total record in seperate query, it turn so slow.

is there another way to return the total record in a faster way

The View is

```
SELECT     dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgTitle, dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgID, dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgDate, dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgActive, 
                      dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgHits, dbo.aspnet_Users.UserName, dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgUserID, dbo.tbl_ImagesDetails.ImgDPath, 
                      dbo.tblUsersExtended.UAvatar, dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgRemarks
FROM         dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster INNER JOIN
                      dbo.aspnet_Users ON dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgUserID = dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_ImagesDetails ON dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster.ImgID = dbo.tbl_ImagesDetails.ImgDParentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblUsersExtended ON dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId = dbo.tblUsersExtended.UUserID
WHERE     (dbo.tbl_ImagesDetails.ImgDDefault = 1)
```

THE SP

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_searchImagestest] 

(
@CurrentPage As int=1,
@PageSize As int=10,
@searchType As int=1,
@Activeflag As bit=null,
@searchTerm as nvarchar(200),
@TotalRecords As int OUTPUT
)
As
begin
-- Turn off count return.
Set NoCount On


    --Full text search
    if @searchType=1
    begin
        select 
            ImgID,ImgTitle,ImgDate,imgHits,UserName,uavatar,RowRank
        from
            (Select
                ImgID,imgtitle,ImgDate,imghits,UserName,UAvatar
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
            From
                 vw_MasterImagesSearch
                WHERE FREETEXT(*, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag)
            ) as MyImages
        where

            RowRank > (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND RowRank <= (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)

-- TOTAL RECORD, WHICH SLOW DOWN THE WHOLE SP EXECUTION
        select @TotalRecords = (select COUNT(*) From vw_MasterImagesSearch 
        WHERE FREETEXT(*, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag))
    end
```

### EDIT

i tried this

Query 1

```
select 
        ImgID,ImgTitle,ImgDate,imgHits,RowRank,TOTALCOUNT,
        (select username from aspnet_Users where UserId=MyImages.imguserid) as username,
        (select UAvatar from tblUsersExtended where UUserID=MyImages.imguserid) as Uavatar

    from
        (Select
            ImgID,imgtitle,ImgDate,imghits,ImgUserID
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
            ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTALCOUNT
        From
             tbl_ImagesMaster
            WHERE FREETEXT(ImgTitle, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag)
        ) as MyImages
    where

        RowRank > (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND RowRank <= (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)
```

Query 2

```
    select 
        ImgID,ImgTitle,ImgDate,imgHits,RowRank,
        (select username from aspnet_Users where UserId=MyImages.imguserid) as username,
        (select UAvatar from tblUsersExtended where UUserID=MyImages.imguserid) as Uavatar

    from
        (Select
            ImgID,imgtitle,ImgDate,imghits,ImgUserID
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
        From
             tbl_ImagesMaster
            WHERE FREETEXT(ImgTitle, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag)
        ) as MyImages
    where

        RowRank > (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND RowRank <= (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)

    select @TotalRecords = (select COUNT(*) From tbl_ImagesMaster
    WHERE FREETEXT(ImgTitle, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag))
```

Query 1 took 3 seconds
Query 2 took less than 1 second

Total rows in the table is 100,000 rows

Comment: I have had a lot of problems in SQL Server when creating complex queries against a view... especially if that view is comprised of other views, which can often be comprised of other views.  My serious advice: in a stored procedure, or any venue not end-user facing, if you can, go against the tables directly.

Comment: @Jeremy : i tried to access the table directly and the query runs so fast, it returned the results with the count in less than 1 second

Answer (score 3):

That 2nd select is running the search all over again. Just alter your paged search:

```
SELECT 
    ImgID,ImgTitle,ImgDate,imgHits,UserName,uavatar,RowRank, TOTALCOUNT
FROM
    (SELECT
        ImgID,
        imgtitle,
        ImgDate,
        imghits,
        UserName,
        UAvatar, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTALCOUNT
    FROM
         vw_MasterImagesSearch
        WHERE FREETEXT(*, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag)
    ) as MyImages
WHERE
    RowRank > (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND RowRank
```

The line

COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTALCOUNT

gives you the count of the internal SELECT before the paging occurs.

Comment: i tried the your solution, but still taking the same amount of time, the problem is in the count. i have 100000 records in the database, the query without the count take less than 1 second

Comment: Have you removed the 2nd query? The "select @TotalRecords" query?

Comment: yes i removed it, however when i access the table directly not through the view even if the second query was there, the result returned in less than one second

Comment: the view is above, but even without the view, the count(*) over() as totalcount is slower than have another query that get the count

Comment: @Moe9977: In [the article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) (one need register to be able to read it) is described *why* `count(*) over()` is slow and how to improve it. I tried to describe the same shortly in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one should change in solution of iKnowKungFoo the part

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTALCOUNT
```

to

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID) AS TotalRows
```

So the second part should contains *reverse* order. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136741/315935) and [the article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) (one needs registration to the last one).

In any way I personally would use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of subqueries. In the way you can define your main set with all rows as CTE. What you need is just execute one get `COUNT(*)` and additionally get the page of data which you need with `WHERE seq BETWEEN (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)`

One more alternative could get `CROSS JOIN` approach instead of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (<reverse sort order>)` (see [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/)) or `UNION` approach (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641139/315935)). I suggest you to test all the ways and find the best one for you.

**UPDATED**: What I mean with CTE is that it can be much better be optimized as views. So first of all you can try the following query

```
WITH MasterImagesSearch AS (
    SELECT im.ImgTitle, im.ImgID, im.ImgDate, im.ImgActive,
           im.ImgHits, asp.UserName, im.ImgUserID, id.ImgDPath,
           e.UAvatar, im.ImgRemarks
    FROM dbo.tbl_ImagesMaster AS im INNER JOIN
           dbo.aspnet_Users AS asp ON im.ImgUserID = asp.UserId INNER JOIN
           dbo.tbl_ImagesDetails AS id ON im.ImgID = id.ImgDParentID INNER JOIN
           dbo.tblUsersExtended AS e ON asp.UserId = e.UUserID
    WHERE id .ImgDDefault = 1
), GetAll AS (
    SELECT ImgID,ImgTitle,ImgDate,imgHits,UserName,uavatar
    FROM MasterImagesSearch
    WHERE FREETEXT(ImgTitle, @searchTerm)
        AND (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag)
), MyImages AS (
    SELECT ImgID,imgtitle,ImgDate,imghitsUserName,uavatar
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID desc) AS RowRank
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID) AS TotalRows
    FROM GetAll
)
SELECT ImgID,imgtitle,ImgDate,imghitsUserName,uavatar
    ,RowRank + TotalRows -1 AS Total
FROM MyImages
WHERE RowRank BETWEEN (@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)
```

I didn't made any additional optimization, but I used CTE with `INNER JOIN` instead of subqueries.

Comment: , your is faster than iKnowKungFoo, but when i compared yours with Query 2 the profiler have less ms in reads, and CPU is way lower, your give 521 MS and the seperate Query 2 above give 61 MS

Comment: @Moe9977: Could you write which queries exactly you tested. I wrote you about tree versions: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID) AS TotalRows` and CTE one having `CROSS JOIN` and another `UNION`. In your question you wrote that Query 2 from your question "took less than 1 second". Now you write about some query which "give 61 MS". How one can understand this?

Comment: the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID) AS TotalRows took 521 ms and Query2 above took 61 ms

Comment: @Moe9977: You should post **full query** which you used. I included the query more detailed which I described before in my answer. I hoped I did no typing errors. Thy this one and compared with your results. If needed you can use `UNION` and `CROSS JOIN` based on the references which I wrote. You can additionally try to use the hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and make tests with different input data. See [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) for more details.

Comment: i tried Query2 and your posted query, and here are the results:  Query 2 CPU=63 MS, Reads : 2635   ,,, your query CPU=1593, Reads 229658. However, i tried to remove `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ImgID) AS TotalRows` and used instead this   `select @TotalRecords = (select COUNT(*) From vw_MasterImagesSearch 
        WHERE FREETEXT(*, @searchTerm) and (@Activeflag IS NULL or ImgActive=@Activeflag))` the reading from the profile has been changed to CPU=375 Reads=5078

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use stored procedure to get query result with parameter, SQL Server generate execution plan for this SP and use this generated execution plan for each you call your SP later. The interesting thing to generate execution plan is table statistics, that SQL Server, use them to generate best execution plan. If parameters of your SP changed may be generated execution plan not usefull and not best execution plan. I think that you must recompile your SP each time want to use whit defrence parameter for calculate execution time. alsow you can use internal parameter in SP to generate execution plan automaticaly by SQL Server for each time of run SP. for example use below code :

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_searchImagestest]
( 
  @CurrentPage As int=1, 
  @PageSize As int=10, 
  @searchType As int=1, 
  @Activeflag As bit=null, 
  @searchTerm as nvarchar(200), 
  @TotalRecords As int OUTPUT 
) 
As begin

Declare       
  @ICurrentPage int, 
  @IPageSize int, 
  @IsearchType int, 
  @IActiveflag bit,
  @IsearchTerm nvarchar(200), 
  @ITotalRecords int 

Set @ICurrentPage = @CurrentPage
Set @IPageSize = @PageSize
Set @IsearchType = @searchType
Set @IActiveflag = Activeflag
Set @IsearchTerm = searchTerm
Set @ITotalRecords = @TotalRecords
```

then use iternal parameter instead of SP parameters.

Comment: @lotfi, i will test that i post the results shortly

Comment: @Lotfi, using internal parameter effected the CPU Time only as per the following: CPU Time is 46MS instead of 62, but total number of reads are the same 2635, therefore with the internal parameter the query executed faster.